# How can I make my Android SwipeableCardViews more like the IOS 7 mail app (swipe to show buttons)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

How can I make my `SwipeableCardViews` more like the IOS 7 mail app (swipe to show buttons)

So far I have created an android application which allows the user to swipe `Cardviews` either to the left or to the right. Each card has 2 buttons, which at a later date I will assign functions to.

(As the image below shows):

[image]

What I would like to accomplish is (but don't yet know how), is instead of swiping to the left or right to completely remove a card.

Instead I would like either swipe gesture, to reveal a button which was hidden underneath the *right* or *left* card.

The IOS 7 mail app already performs this function (screenshot below) I would like to perform this in Android using `Cardviews` **(not `ListViews`)**.

*How can I go about doing this?*

[image]

**My code so far:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private CardViewAdapter mAdapter;

    private ArrayList<String> mItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mItems = new ArrayList<>(30);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            mItems.add(String.format("Card number %2d", i));
        }

        OnItemTouchListener itemTouchListener = new OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCardViewTap(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tapped " + mItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onButton1Click(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Button1 in " + mItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onButton2Click(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Button2 in " + mItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        mAdapter = new CardViewAdapter(mItems, itemTouchListener);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener =
                new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(mRecyclerView,
                        new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canSwipe(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismissedBySwipeLeft(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    mItems.remove(position);
                                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                }
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    mItems.remove(position);
                                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                }
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(swipeTouchListener);
    }

    /**
     * Interface for the touch events in each item
     */
    public interface OnItemTouchListener {
        /**
         * Callback invoked when the user Taps one of the RecyclerView items
         *
         * @param view     the CardView touched
         * @param position the index of the item touched in the RecyclerView
         */
        public void onCardViewTap(View view, int position);

        /**
         * Callback invoked when the Button1 of an item is touched
         *
         * @param view     the Button touched
         * @param position the index of the item touched in the RecyclerView
         */
        public void onButton1Click(View view, int position);

        /**
         * Callback invoked when the Button2 of an item is touched
         *
         * @param view     the Button touched
         * @param position the index of the item touched in the RecyclerView
         */
        public void onButton2Click(View view, int position);
    }

    /**
     * A simple adapter that loads a CardView layout with one TextView and two Buttons, and
     * listens to clicks on the Buttons or on the CardView
     */
    public class CardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private List<String> cards;
        private OnItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener;

        public CardViewAdapter(List<String> cards, OnItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener) {
            this.cards = cards;
            this.onItemTouchListener = onItemTouchListener;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            viewHolder.title.setText(cards.get(i));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return cards == null ? 0 : cards.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView title;
            private Button button1;
            private Button button2;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_title);
                button1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_button1);
                button2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_button2);

                button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onItemTouchListener.onButton1Click(v, getPosition());
                    }
                });

                button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onItemTouchListener.onButton2Click(v, getPosition());
                    }
                });

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onItemTouchListener.onCardViewTap(v, getPosition());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.java**

```
public class SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    // Cached ViewConfiguration and system-wide constant values
    private int mSlop;
    private int mMinFlingVelocity;
    private int mMaxFlingVelocity;
    private long mAnimationTime;

    // Fixed properties
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private SwipeListener mSwipeListener;
    private int mViewWidth = 1; // 1 and not 0 to prevent dividing by zero

    // Transient properties
    private List<PendingDismissData> mPendingDismisses = new ArrayList<>();
    private int mDismissAnimationRefCount = 0;
    private float mDownX;
    private float mDownY;
    private boolean mSwiping;
    private int mSwipingSlop;
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
    private int mDownPosition;
    private View mDownView;
    private boolean mPaused;
    private float mFinalDelta;

    /**
     * Constructs a new swipe touch listener for the given {@link android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView}
     *
     * @param recyclerView The recycler view whose items should be dismissable by swiping.
     * @param listener     The listener for the swipe events.
     */
    public SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(RecyclerView recyclerView, SwipeListener listener) {
        ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(recyclerView.getContext());
        mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
        mMinFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity() * 16;
        mMaxFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
        mAnimationTime = recyclerView.getContext().getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mSwipeListener = listener;


        /**
         * This will ensure that this SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener is paused during list view scrolling.
         * If a scroll listener is already assigned, the caller should still pass scroll changes through
         * to this listener.
         */
        mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                setEnabled(newState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Enables or disables (pauses or resumes) watching for swipe-to-dismiss gestures.
     *
     * @param enabled Whether or not to watch for gestures.
     */
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mPaused = !enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return handleTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        handleTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    private boolean handleTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (mViewWidth < 2) {
            mViewWidth = mRecyclerView.getWidth();
        }

        switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                if (mPaused) {
                    break;
                }

                // Find the child view that was touched (perform a hit test)
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                int childCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
                int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
                mRecyclerView.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
                int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
                int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
                View child;
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    child = mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                    child.getHitRect(rect);
                    if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                        mDownView = child;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (mDownView != null) {
                    mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                    mDownY = motionEvent.getRawY();
                    mDownPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(mDownView);
                    if (mSwipeListener.canSwipe(mDownPosition)) {
                        mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                    } else {
                        mDownView = null;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    break;
                }

                if (mDownView != null && mSwiping) {
                    // cancel
                    mDownView.animate()
                            .translationX(0)
                            .alpha(1)
                            .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                            .setListener(null);
                }
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                mVelocityTracker = null;
                mDownX = 0;
                mDownY = 0;
                mDownView = null;
                mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
                mSwiping = false;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    break;
                }

                mFinalDelta = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
                float velocityX = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity();
                float absVelocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
                float absVelocityY = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
                boolean dismiss = false;
                boolean dismissRight = false;
                if (Math.abs(mFinalDelta) > mViewWidth / 2 && mSwiping) {
                    dismiss = true;
                    dismissRight = mFinalDelta > 0;
                } else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= absVelocityX && absVelocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity
                        && absVelocityY < absVelocityX && mSwiping) {
                    // dismiss only if flinging in the same direction as dragging
                    dismiss = (velocityX < 0) == (mFinalDelta < 0);
                    dismissRight = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
                }
                if (dismiss && mDownPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    // dismiss
                    final View downView = mDownView; // mDownView gets null'd before animation ends
                    final int downPosition = mDownPosition;
                    ++mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                    mDownView.animate()
                            .translationX(dismissRight ? mViewWidth : -mViewWidth)
                            .alpha(0)
                            .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    performDismiss(downView, downPosition);
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    // cancel
                    mDownView.animate()
                            .translationX(0)
                            .alpha(1)
                            .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                            .setListener(null);
                }
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                mVelocityTracker = null;
                mDownX = 0;
                mDownY = 0;
                mDownView = null;
                mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
                mSwiping = false;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null || mPaused) {
                    break;
                }

                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                float deltaY = motionEvent.getRawY() - mDownY;
                if (!mSwiping && Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop && Math.abs(deltaY) < Math.abs(deltaX) / 2) {
                    mSwiping = true;
                    mSwipingSlop = (deltaX > 0 ? mSlop : -mSlop);
                }

                if (mSwiping) {
                    mDownView.setTranslationX(deltaX - mSwipingSlop);
                    mDownView.setAlpha(Math.max(0f, Math.min(1f,
                            1f - Math.abs(deltaX) / mViewWidth)));
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void performDismiss(final View dismissView, final int dismissPosition) {
        // Animate the dismissed list item to zero-height and fire the dismiss callback when
        // all dismissed list item animations have completed. This triggers layout on each animation
        // frame; in the future we may want to do something smarter and more performant.

        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = dismissView.getLayoutParams();
        final int originalHeight = dismissView.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);

        animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                --mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                if (mDismissAnimationRefCount == 0) {
                    // No active animations, process all pending dismisses.
                    // Sort by descending position
                    Collections.sort(mPendingDismisses);

                    int[] dismissPositions = new int[mPendingDismisses.size()];
                    for (int i = mPendingDismisses.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        dismissPositions[i] = mPendingDismisses.get(i).position;
                    }

                    if (mFinalDelta > 0) {
                        mSwipeListener.onDismissedBySwipeRight(mRecyclerView, dismissPositions);
                    } else {
                        mSwipeListener.onDismissedBySwipeLeft(mRecyclerView, dismissPositions);
                    }

                    // Reset mDownPosition to avoid MotionEvent.ACTION_UP trying to start a dismiss
                    // animation with a stale position
                    mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
                    for (PendingDismissData pendingDismiss : mPendingDismisses) {
                        // Reset view presentation
                        pendingDismiss.view.setAlpha(1f);
                        pendingDismiss.view.setTranslationX(0);
                        lp = pendingDismiss.view.getLayoutParams();
                        lp.height = originalHeight;
                        pendingDismiss.view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    }

                    // Send a cancel event
                    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(time, time,
                            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, 0, 0, 0);
                    mRecyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(cancelEvent);

                    mPendingDismisses.clear();
                }
            }
        });

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                lp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                dismissView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        });

        mPendingDismisses.add(new PendingDismissData(dismissPosition, dismissView));
        animator.start();
    }

    /**
     * The callback interface used by {@link SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener} to inform its client
     * about a swipe of one or more list item positions.
     */
    public interface SwipeListener {
        /**
         * Called to determine whether the given position can be swiped.
         */
        boolean canSwipe(int position);

        /**
         * Called when the item has been dismissed by swiping to the left.
         *
         * @param recyclerView           The originating {@link android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView}.
         * @param reverseSortedPositions An array of positions to dismiss, sorted in descending
         *                               order for convenience.
         */
        void onDismissedBySwipeLeft(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);

        /**
         * Called when the item has been dismissed by swiping to the right.
         *
         * @param recyclerView           The originating {@link android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView}.
         * @param reverseSortedPositions An array of positions to dismiss, sorted in descending
         *                               order for convenience.
         */
        void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);
    }

    class PendingDismissData implements Comparable<PendingDismissData> {
        public int position;
        public View view;

        public PendingDismissData(int position, View view) {
            this.position = position;
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(@NonNull PendingDismissData other) {
            // Sort by descending position
            return other.position - position;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**card_view_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_view_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/card_view_title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/card_view_button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/card_view_button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I am also trying to implement the same with RecyclerView and CardviewAdapter but unable to find the exact solution.  if you find some solution or way how to proceed next, can you please share with us.

Answer (score 5):

Just for a reference you can use these [swipe layout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) library . its includes swiping actions which you were searching . Hope it ill be helpful

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've just done this. This is how it looks like:

[image]

I don't have any `CardView` but **you can have any layout** (so you can add the support lib `CardView` or whatever you like).

This is how I did it. I used [this library](https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo). Since the library has `minSdkVersion` 15 and we have 14, I copy-pasted the following classes directly from GitHub: `OnItemClickListener`, `RecyclerViewAdapter`, `SwipeableItemClickListener`, `SwipeToDismissTouchListener` and `ViewAdapter` (this are the only ones you need if you use a `RecyclerView`).

Because the lib has not been updated yet, you'll need to add the following method into `SwipeableItemClickListener`:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
}
```

Your list item layout should have the following structure:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_article_height"
    >

    <!-- This is the layout you see always -->    
    <include
        layout="@layout/list_item_article"
        tools:visibility="gone"
        />

    <!-- This is the layout shown after swiping. Must have visibility="gone" -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/swipe_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/swipe_cancel"
            android:gravity="center"
            />    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/swipe_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/swipe_delete"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />    
    </LinearLayout>    
</FrameLayout>
```

Then simply add this code to your `Activity/Fragment` after creating the `RecyclerView` and setting it's adapter:

```
final SwipeToDismissTouchListener<RecyclerViewAdapter> touchListener =
        new SwipeToDismissTouchListener<>(
                new RecyclerViewAdapter(mRecyclerView),
                new SwipeToDismissTouchListener.DismissCallbacks<RecyclerViewAdapter>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerView, int position) {
                        // remove item at position and notify adapter
                    }
                }
        );
mRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener((RecyclerView.OnScrollListener) touchListener.makeScrollListener());
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new SwipeableItemClickListener(
        getActivity(),
        new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                if (view.getId() == R.id.swipe_delete) {
                    touchListener.processPendingDismisses();
                } else {
                    touchListener.undoPendingDismiss();
                }
            }
        }
));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have only add and delete button you can use RecyclerView but with RecyclerView.Adapter not CardViewAdapter.
Here is an example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    ...
}

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                               .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ...
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```