# Swipe and tap to enlarge recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view which has its items in a card view. The recycler view gets its data from a sql database within the app . Now I want to implement two features to this recycler view items. First , whenever the individual cards are tapped , I want them to enlarge and display more data and should shrink back when tapped again. It is not like the case of expandable list view where it expands into a child list view. I want the height of the card to increase and just show some more information and buttons. Second I want the items to swipe left . I know there is a feature for that in recycler view , but I want to customise the swipe feature. Swipe from right should be locked , and when swiped from left , It should not go off list completely. It should show two buttons and should go off list only when one of the buttons is clicked. I have been looking , but there is no proper explaination anywhere. Please guide me through this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, set the adapter `layout_height` to `wrap_content` and set the buttons visibility to `GONE`. Implement the `OnClick` listener in the RecyclerView adapter and set the visibility of the buttons to `VISIBLE` if `GONE` and `GONE` if `VISIBLE` or use a boolean to alternate the visibility.

For your second question, this might help:

https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/custom-swipe-recyclerview.html

[How can I make my Android SwipeableCardViews more like the IOS 7 mail app (swipe to show buttons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107692/how-can-i-make-my-android-swipeablecardviews-more-like-the-ios-7-mail-app-swipe)

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Comment: I was just looking at that post from learn2crack. That is a good solution , but when I swipe , I dont want the list item to go off list completely. I want it to show two buttons which then will perform specific functions. Thats the part which is confusing me the most. I want something like this . [link] (https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView). This is available only for list view

Comment: See my updated answer ..Please mark the answer correct if it helped.Thanks!